# accessing a class from a BroadcastReceiver object

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to add some code to an open source android download manager library, and I have encountered a problem. This code contains a class called DownloadManager that enables simultaneous downloads. Since I want my code to only download one file at a time, and keep the rest in a queue and pass it to the DownloadManager class as the earlier one has finished, I wrote my own class that extended the DownloadManager. I also had to write another class, MyReceiver, to receive on download complete broadcasts so I know when to start to download the next file in line. 
The problem is I want to pass the next file once OnReceive() method has been called, but I do not have access to the properties of class DownloadManager. Plus, I can't create a new object of this class within my Receiver class as its constructor needs a ContentResolver object as an argument.

Here is the code of my extended DownloadManager class:

```
public class MyDownloadManager extends DownloadManager {
    public ArrayList<Request> list;
    public boolean activeDownloadExists;

    public MyDownloadManager(ContentResolver resolver, String packageName) {
        super(resolver, packageName);
        list = new ArrayList<DownloadManager.Request>();
        activeDownloadExists = false;

    }

    public void addToWaitingList(Request request) {
        if (!activeDownloadExists) {
            enqueue(request);
            activeDownloadExists = true;

        } else
            list.add(request);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of MyReceiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ArrayList<Request> list;
    public boolean activeDownloadExists;
    public IntentFilter filter;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("OnReceive" , "Received");
    }

}
```

The open source I talked about is available here: https://github.com/yxl/DownloadProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea that I tried and worked ( although it meant making fundamental changes in the structure of the code ) was that instead of writing the code for MyDownloadManager as a separate file, I rewrote it as an inner class in the file where MyReceiver was located.
I believe this doesn't comply with software engineering rules, but it works!